# UINavigationController reloading UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

In my application I am parsing XML to create a UITableView. When a user selects a row it changes the file that it is parsing and reloads the UITableView.

I want to create a back button so that the user can go back the the previous XML page they were viewing.

In short how can I tell the navigation controller to create a back arrow for this page when all i am doing is reloading my UITableView?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest building *another* controller (i.e. UITableViewController) and push that instead of just reloading the table. This makes the button automagically, *and* (major plus here), it animates the whole digging down / stepping back in a way that the user is expecting it.

As a side note, I didn't manage to get a back-style button once I tried it, just a plain normal button (make a new button and set it at the navigation bar).

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a navigation.  Rather than reloading the table's data, simply push a  new view controller onto the navigation stack every time a row is tapped.  This is a fundamental pattern in iPhone development.  Here is [Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html) for a multi-level drill down table view.

Comment: I can't push a new tableView I have probably 20,000 XML files that are all parsed the same way. I can't create a new View controller for every XML file.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but couldn't you build a generic controller for displaying XML data?  The view controller could push instances of itself, passing the required XML into its initializer.

Comment: But wouldn't that limit how far the user can go into the hierarchy.

Comment: In that you'll eventually run out of memory, yes.  Are there cycles in your navigation graph?